# getting the absolute path of a file inside several directories and subdirectories

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am supposed to get the absolute path of a file which is present in dir3.
the path is

```
"C:\\Workspace\\folder1\\folder2\\file"
```

And the only input I am supposed to provide is the name of the file and the name of the major directory in C drive i.e. Workspace.

Can I get the absolute path using any inbuilt function in python. I tried using this code but it gave me erroneous results:

```
import os

x='workspace'
y='file_name'
path_1=os.path.abspath("workspace/file_name")
print(path_1)
```

output:

```
C:\Workspace\workspace\file_name
```

Comment: Where is your python script located and run from in relation to the folder you are talking about?

Comment: its located inside workspace itself.

Comment: then dont add workspace to abspath as you there already..

Comment: the fact is the code should work for any no.of directories.the file may be located in workspace itself.it can be inside another folder which is in workspace or multiple such folders.So i cant do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work with

```
os.path.abspath("workspace/file_name")
```

Edit:
I tried in python console a few secs ago:

```
import os
os.path.abspath("Bachelor/simpleOpenCL.py")
'/home/julius/Bachelor/simpleOpenCL.py'
```

Comment: its not..i just gave you the output its providing me the same output again and again.I have checked it with other files as well...unless my file is in workspace itself the path function isnt working

Comment: This isn't what the OP's question is asking for. He is stating that he has the head of a file structure (home) in your case, and a file that is somewhere in the structure so /home/simpleOpenCL.py

Answer (score 0):

The builtin doesn't work like that BUT you can pretty handily make your own function using some methods from os

Assuming python 3.0

```
os.walk
```

Assuming python 2.7

```
os.path.walk
```

Basically, you can split the path you are given using os.path.split() then us the walk method with the head and check if the tail is in the result. If you find it you can do os.path.abspath on the tail to get the abspath of that file

```
def locate(headnname):
    abspaths = []
    head,tail = os.path.split(headnname)
    if not os.path.isdir(head):
        raise IOError("not a valid head: %s" % head)
    for dp,dn,fn in os.walk(head):
        if tail in fn:
            abspaths.append(dp+"/"+tail)
    return abspaths
```

output:

```
>>> locate("D:/users/admin/pytools.py")
['D:/users/admin\\Programs\\AT_Plotter\\src/pytools.py',
 'D:/users/admin\\Programs\\py2exe/pytools.py',
 'D:/users/admin\\Programs\\pytools\\src/pytools.py',
 'D:/users/admin\\Shared\\pyIO/pytools.py',
 'D:/users/admin\\Shared\\pyIO\\Old/pytools.py']
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Active State Recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/499305/).

There's function definition to do recursive file searchs

```
import os, fnmatch

def locate(pattern, root=os.curdir):
    '''Locate all files matching supplied filename pattern in and below
    supplied root directory.'''
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(root)):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
            yield os.path.join(path, filename)
```

Example use of the function:

```
for x in locate("*.zip", "C:\\Temp"):
    print x
```